# How do I prevent getting a routing error while trying to access a href

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have href rendered as "www.yahoo.com", but when the user clicks on it instead of re-directing to http://www.yahoo.com the page says Route not found error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Post the code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<%= link_to "Click Me", "http://www.yahoo.com" %>
```

it's need to put `http://` before address.

**Updated (according to your comment)**

ok then just do this:

let,

```
@url = "www.yahoo.com"
```

now,

```
<%= link_to "Click Me", "http://#{@url}" %>
```

Comment: The URL is actually entered by the user and in some cases, they don't have it which is causing the problem. I don't have http or https://. It just has www.yahoo.com

Comment: I just updated my answer according to your comment please check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your html should be changed from

```
<a href="www.yahoo.com">www.yahoo.com</a>
```

to

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">www.yahoo.com</a>
```